# How to customize Jekyll Minima's Subscribe button

Tags: html, css, jekyll, jekyll-theme, minima

I am building a GitHub blog with [FastPages](https://github.com/fastai/fastpages).

The automated process to create articles from Jupyter notebooks is working fine. However, the "Subscribe" button at the bottom of the page points to https://my_git_account.github.io/My_FastPages_Blog/feed.xml, which leads to an error page saying, "This XML file does not appear to have any style information ..."

I have followed FastPages's instruction [here](https://github.com/fastai/fastpages#subscribing-with-rss), and checked this [issue](https://github.com/fastai/fastpages/issues/486). Unfortunately, there were no clear answers.
I'd like to modify the "Subscribe" button to point to the RSS link (for example https://feedrabbit.com/?url=https://my_git_account.github.io/My_FastPages_Blog/feed.xml.

Any advice on how should I do this? As I struggled to find my way by modifying the _config.yml file and the index.html files, it was not working, as whenever I ran: `make server`. All the files were generated as before.

I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Answer (score 0):

After a while, I found the answer by myself.

In case someone needs this, here is what I did:

- I went to download the footer.html from Jekyll Git [repo](https://github.com/jekyll/minima/).
- Next, I override its HTML contents:

```html
    <p class="feed-subscribe">
      <a href="https://feedrabbit.com/?url=https:put_the_link_you_want_HERE">
        <svg class="svg-icon orange">
          <use xlink:href="{{ 'assets/minima-social-icons.svg#rss' | relative_url }}"></use>
        </svg><span>Subscribe</span>
      </a>
</p>
```

I hope the Fastpages team can update this solution, the Subscribe button in their template has been unused for so long.